# Arrayadapter add method not accepting string values

Tags: java, android

I am running an app on Android Studio and while adding string values to arrayadapter object, I get null pointer exception. My exact relevant code is:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {

                List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
                wordList = Arrays.asList(result);
                if(wordList!= null)
                {
                    for(String forecast: wordList)
                    {
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"forecast value: "+forecast);
                        mForecastAdapter.add(forecast);
                    }
                  //  mForecastAdapter.addAll(wordList);

                }
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Sorry!! Result is null");

            }
```

I tried with `addAll()` method as well, but for that I need to upgrade to API 11. So that is not an option. For Information: This result variable is not empty and in logs, I do get correct value of forecast every time I execute this set of code.
The exception that I get is:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.khatri.sunshine.app;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {
    String[] resultfinal = new String[100];
    public ForecastFragment() {
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                // Add this line in order for this fragment to handle menu events.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {

            FetchWeatherTask fetchWeatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
                    fetchWeatherTask.execute("94043");
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>();
        weekForecast.add("Today-Sunny-88/63");
        weekForecast.add("Tomorrow FOggy 77/46");
        weekForecast.add("Day after sunny again 45/34");
        weekForecast.add("Thur-foggy again 65/34");
        weekForecast.add("Fri afternoon rainy 76/32");
        weekForecast.add("Sat happy sat 65/12");
        weekForecast.add("Day after sunny again 45/34");
        weekForecast.add("Thur-foggy again 65/34");
        weekForecast.add("Fri afternoon rainy 76/32");
        weekForecast.add("Sat happy sat 65/12");

        ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        getContext(),
        R.layout.list_item_forecast,
        R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
        weekForecast);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);


        return rootView;

    }

    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

// Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;

            String format = "json";
            String units = "metric";
            int numDays = 7;
            String appid = "c70ffaa8bf3c10556dc3e82d72d23677";

            try {

                final String FORECAST_BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
                final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
                final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
                final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
                final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";
                final String APPID_PARAM = "appid";

                Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                        .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                        .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                        .appendQueryParameter(APPID_PARAM, appid)
                        .build();

                URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Built URI " + builtUri.toString());

                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    forecastJsonStr = null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    forecastJsonStr = null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "forecast JSON string: " + forecastJsonStr);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);

                forecastJsonStr = null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        resultfinal = getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, numDays);
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                    catch (JSONException jsonexception)
                    {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"JSON Exception",jsonexception);
                    }
                }
            }
            return resultfinal;
        }



        private String getReadableDateString(long time) {
            SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
            return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
        }

        private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
            // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
            long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
            long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

            String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
            return highLowStr;
        }


        private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
                throws JSONException {

            // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
            final String OWM_LIST = "list";
            final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
            final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
            final String OWM_MAX = "max";
            final String OWM_MIN = "min";
            final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

            JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);


            Time dayTime = new Time();
            dayTime.setToNow();


            int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);


            dayTime = new Time();

            String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
            for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
                // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
                String day;
                String description;
                String highAndLow;

                // Get the JSON object representing the day
                JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert that
                // into something human-readable, since most people won't read "1400356800" as
                // "this saturday".
                long dateTime;
                // Cheating to convert this to UTC time, which is what we want anyhow
                dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);
                day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

                // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
                JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
                description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

                // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to name variables
                // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
                JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
                double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
                double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

                highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
                resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;

            }

            for (String s : resultStrs) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast entry: " + s);
            }
            //onPostExecute(resultStrs);

            return resultStrs;



        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {

            List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
                   wordList = Arrays.asList(result);
            if(wordList!= null)
            {

               // mForecastAdapter.add(result.toString());
                for(String forecast: wordList)
                {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"forecast value: "+forecast);
                    mForecastAdapter.add(forecast);
                }
              //  mForecastAdapter.addAll(wordList);

            }
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Sorry!! Reuslt is null");

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Have you initialized your mForecastAdapter variable? Can you put complete code here

Comment: Because you are not initialize the ArrayAdapter and try to add value, Please first initialize your arrayAdapter then after add value

Comment: Did you check if your wordlist is empty or not ? Can you put a size condition on wordList and try again ?

Comment: @SachinSaxena I did ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        getContext(),
        R.layout.list_item_forecast,
        R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
        weekForecast);

on my OnCreateView() method. Now I want to add values to this same object.

Comment: your arraylist is not initialized correctly, so can you put complete code here please, or check your wordlist is not empty.

Comment: Please put complete code here.

Comment: @BorisS. No array list is not empty, that is why, I am getting correct logs of forecast entry.

Comment: Are you sur that all your values are not null ?

Comment: @BorisS. Yes. Checked all values. None of them is null.

Comment: You can take your ArrayAdapter variable globally and than after initialize it

Comment: @ShaileshLimbadiya If you see my code, its already done like that.

Comment: Which statement is giving `NullPointerException`? Have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you take global variable then you just initialize first time and you use in you whole class. I hope this will help you and you got your solution.

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

        ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ......
        mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            getContext(),
                            R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                            R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                            weekForecast);

        .....       
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Shailesh, corrected it now. Have one more doubt, if you could help me with that as well.

Now when I am setting listview.setAdapter(mforecastAdapter) in my onPostExecute() method, it is not showing on the emulator screen.

I made ListView listview as global and initialised it in onCreateView() and tried to set value in onPostExecute().

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Yea sure, it's my Pleasure to help you, you mean to work on device but problem with emulator right?

Answer (score 0):

You initialised the local mForecastAdapter variable in oncreateView() and adding values to global mForecastAdapter which is not initialized. Thats why it is giving you null pointer.

Comment: Thanks Sumeet, it was such a small mistake. Corrected it now.

Comment: Now when I am setting listview.setAdapter(mforecastAdapter) in my onPostExecute() method, it is not showing on the emulator screen.

I made ListView listview as global and initialised it in onCreateView() and tried to set value in onPostExecute().

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

the point is the lifeCycle of fragment.
Can you ensure that the onCreteView() method has been called be before you call the onOptionsItemSelected() menthod ?

I suggest you to add some log code or set some breadpoints to see which method has been called first.

Comment: It is the onCreateView() method only, since it gets called first.

Comment: I got the answer for this one....

clear the arrayadapter, mforecastAdapter.clear() then,
add values to this adapter and then,
mForecastAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

This depicted the change in my list view :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for this from another thread:

clear the arrayadapter, mforecastAdapter.clear() then,
add values to this adapter and then,
mForecastAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

This depicted the change in my list view :)